# Multiprocessing python program inside Docker

Tags: python, docker, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to test multiprocessing for python inside a docker container but even, if the processes are created successfully (I have 8 CPUs and 8 processes are created), they always take only one physical CPU.
Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
import pandas
import numpy
from scipy.stats import linregress
import random
import logging

def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func):
    retLst = Parallel(n_jobs=multiprocessing.cpu_count())(delayed(func)(group) for name, group in dfGrouped)
    return pandas.concat(retLst)

def compute_regression(df):
    result = {}

    (slope,intercept,rvalue,pvalue,stderr) = linregress(df.date,df.value)
    result["slope"] = [slope]
    result["intercept"] = [intercept]

    return pandas.DataFrame(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logging.info("start")
    random_list = []
    for i in range(1,10000):
        for j in range(1,100):
            random_list.append({"id":i,"date":j,"value":random.random()})

    df = pandas.DataFrame(random_list)

    df = applyParallel(df.groupby('id'), compute_regression)

    logging.info("end")
```

I tried multiple docker options when I launch like --cpus or --cpuset but it is always using only 1 physical CPUs.
Is it an issue in Docker, python, the OS?
Docker version is 1.13.1

The result of the `cpu_count()`:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> multiprocessing.cpu_count()
8
```

During the run, here is a top. We can see the main process and the 8 child processes but I find the percentages weird.
[image: top screenshot]

And then, if I change to 4 processes, total amount of CPU used is always the same:
[image: top with 4 threads]

Comment: If you are running Docker on a Mac or Windows, it runs inside of a VM. You need to configure Docker as a whole to allocate more CPUs to that VM. Options to ``docker run`` don't override that, you can't only use up to as many as VM is allowed to use.

Comment: It s actually running inside Linux :(

Comment: can you do a `print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())` and add the result in your question?

Comment: @hansaplast I added the screenshot

Comment: is that from within docker?

Comment: @hansaplast no, from the root machine

Comment: can you do that from within docker? Because that's exactly the question: "how many cores does docker get to use from the host system?"

Comment: @angelwally Have you solved the problem in the end? I'm experiencing the same same thing with the Pathos library.

Comment: @DCS No in the end i change my architecture to have multiple dockers :/

Comment: @hanego 

can you share the Dockerfile, please? And result of running `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` inside the container?

Comment: Sorry I don't have it anymore, I opened this issue almost 3 years ago :/

Answer (score 19):

From https://docs.docker.com/get-started - "Fundamentally, a container is nothing but a running process, with some added encapsulation features applied to it in order to keep it isolated from the host and from other containers."

Docker runs on a host machine. That host machine (or virtual machine) has a certain number of physical (or virtual) CPU's. The reason that `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` displays 8 in your case is because that is the number of CPU's your system has. Using docker options like `--cpus` or `--cpuset-cpus` doesn't change your machine's hardware, which is what `cpu_count()` is reporting.

On my current system:

```
# native
$ python -c 'import multiprocessing as mp; print(mp.cpu_count())'
12
# docker
$ docker run -it --rm --cpus 1 --cpuset-cpus 0 python python -c 'import multiprocessing as mp; print(mp.cpu_count())'
12
```

From https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu - "By default, each container’s access to the host machine’s CPU cycles is unlimited."
But you can limit containers with options like `--cpus` or `--cpuset-cpus`.

`--cpus` can be a floating point number up to the number of physical CPU's available. You can think of this number as a numerator in the fraction `<--cpus arg>`/`<physical CPU's>`. If you have 8 physical CPU's and you specify `--cpus 4`, what you're telling docker is to use no more than 50% (4/8) of your total CPU's. `--cpus 1.5` would use 18.75% (1.5/8).

`--cpuset-cpus` actually does limit specifically which physical/virtual CPU's to use.

(And there are many other CPU-related options that are covered in docker's documentation.)

Here is a smaller code sample:

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
import sys

import psutil
from joblib.parallel import Parallel, delayed

def get_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    if not logger.hasHandlers():
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(process)d/%(processName)s] %(message)s")
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return logger

def fn1(n):
    get_logger().debug("fn1(%d); cpu# %d", n, psutil.Process().cpu_num())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_logger().debug("main")
    Parallel(n_jobs=multiprocessing.cpu_count())(delayed(fn1)(n) for n in range(1, 101))
```

Running this both natively and within docker will log lines such as:

```
[21/LokyProcess-2] fn1(81); cpu# 11
[28/LokyProcess-9] fn1(82); cpu# 6
[29/LokyProcess-10] fn1(83); cpu# 2
[31/LokyProcess-12] fn1(84); cpu# 0
[22/LokyProcess-3] fn1(85); cpu# 3
[23/LokyProcess-4] fn1(86); cpu# 1
[20/LokyProcess-1] fn1(87); cpu# 7
[25/LokyProcess-6] fn1(88); cpu# 3
[27/LokyProcess-8] fn1(89); cpu# 4
[21/LokyProcess-2] fn1(90); cpu# 9
[28/LokyProcess-9] fn1(91); cpu# 10
[26/LokyProcess-7] fn1(92); cpu# 11
[22/LokyProcess-3] fn1(95); cpu# 9
[29/LokyProcess-10] fn1(93); cpu# 2
[24/LokyProcess-5] fn1(94); cpu# 10
[23/LokyProcess-4] fn1(96); cpu# 1
[20/LokyProcess-1] fn1(97); cpu# 9
[23/LokyProcess-4] fn1(98); cpu# 1
[27/LokyProcess-8] fn1(99); cpu# 4
[21/LokyProcess-2] fn1(100); cpu# 5
```

Notice that all 12 CPU's are in use on my system.
Notice that

- the same physical CPU is used by multiple processes (cpu#3 by process #'s 22 & 25)
- one individual process can use multiple CPU's (process #21 uses CPU #'s 11 & 9)

Running the same program with `docker run --cpus 1 ...` will still result in all 12 CPU's being used by all 12 processes started, just as if the --cpus argument wasn't present. It just limits percentage of total CPU time docker is allowed to use.

Running the same program with `docker run --cpusets-cpus 0-1 ...` will result in only 2 physical CPU's being used by all 12 processes started:

```
[11/LokyProcess-2] fn1(35); cpu# 0
[11/LokyProcess-2] fn1(36); cpu# 0
[12/LokyProcess-3] fn1(37); cpu# 1
[11/LokyProcess-2] fn1(38); cpu# 0
[15/LokyProcess-6] fn1(39); cpu# 1
[17/LokyProcess-8] fn1(40); cpu# 0
[11/LokyProcess-2] fn1(41); cpu# 0
[10/LokyProcess-1] fn1(42); cpu# 1
[11/LokyProcess-2] fn1(43); cpu# 1
[13/LokyProcess-4] fn1(44); cpu# 1
[12/LokyProcess-3] fn1(45); cpu# 0
[12/LokyProcess-3] fn1(46); cpu# 1
```

To answer the statement "they always take only one physical CPU"-- this is only true if the `--cpusets-cpus` arg is exactly/only 1 CPU.

---

(As a side note-- the reason for logging being set up the way it is in the example is becuase of an [open bug](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/692) in joblib.)

Answer (score 6):

`multiprocessing.cpu_count()` gives **2** on my machine without passing `--cpu` option

headover to https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#cpu for more information about docker container resources

Answer (score 4):

Try creating machine from scratch (replace numerical values with desired ones):

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-cpu-count=8 --virtualbox-memory=8192 --virtualbox-disk-size=10000 default
```

This is just to be on a safe side.
And now important part:

Specify cores number before running your image. Following command will use 8 cores.

```
docker run -it --cpuset-cpus="0-7" your_image_name
```

And check in docker, if you succeeded not only in python with

```
nproc
```

Good luck and let us know how it went  !

Answer (score 4):

You can test that the multiprocessor is working fine by doing the following commands:

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu:20.04
root@somehash:/# apt update && apt install stress
root@somehash:/# stress --cpu 8 # 8 if you have 8 cores
```

If you have multiple cores, you can test in another terminal the command `htop` or `top` and you should see all the cores running. If you used `htop` you should see something as follows.

[image]

If you are at this step. Then everything is working fine.
Furthermore, as I run the script you provided I see my processors being used as they should, you can the the image below. (I also add the process to show it, I run your script inside an `ipython` terminal. I also changed `from sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel import Parallel, delayed` to `from joblib.parallel import Parallel, delayed` because it was not working for me otherwise).

[image]

I hope the information provided helps. For other clues, you might like to check your version of `docker`.

Answer (score 2):

```
''' Distributed load among several Docker containers using Python multiprocessing capabilities '''

import random
import time
import subprocess
import queue
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, Lock

LOCK = Lock()
TEST_QUEUE = Queue()


class TestWorker(object):
    ''' This Class is executed by each container '''

    @staticmethod
    def run_test(container_id, value):
        ''' Operation to be executed for each container '''

        cmd = ['docker exec -it {0} echo "I am container {0}!, this is message: {1}"' \
                .format(container_id, value)]
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in process.stdout:
            print(line.decode('utf-8')[:-2])
        process.wait()

    @staticmethod
    def container(container_id):
        ''' Here we get a value from the shared queue '''

        while not TEST_QUEUE.empty():
            LOCK.acquire()
            try:
                value = TEST_QUEUE.get(block=False)
                time.sleep(0.5)
            except queue.Empty:
                print("Queue empty ):")
                return
            print("\nProcessing: {0}\n".format(value))
            LOCK.release()
            TestWorker.run_test(container_id, value)

def master():
    ''' Main controller to set containers and test values '''

    qty = input("How many containers you want to deploy: ")
    msg_val = input("How many random values you want to send among this containers: ")

    print("\nGenerating test messages...\n")
    for _ in range(int(msg_val)):
        item = random.randint(1000, 9999)
        TEST_QUEUE.put(item)
    ids = []
    for _ in range(int(qty)):
        container_id = subprocess.run(["docker", "run", "-it", "-d", "centos:7"], \
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        container_id = container_id.stdout.decode('utf-8')[:-1]
        ids.append(container_id)
    pool = Pool(int(qty))
    pool.map(TestWorker.container, ids)
    pool.close()

master()
```